# Provide schema for xsd:any element while importing WSDL using wsimport

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, wsdl, wsimport

I have a WSDL that uses an `xsd:any` element in a return type for one of the methods, like this:

```
<xs:element name="Method_XMLResponse">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Method_XMLResult">
        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:any/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

When I run the WSDL through the `wsimport` tool, I get a generated class that has this `xs:any` field mapped as a list of objects:

```
public static class MethodXMLResult {

    @XmlMixed
    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    protected List<Object> content;

}
```

When invoking the service using the generated code, I get instances of `org.w3c.dom.Node` in the `content` list (`com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl` to be precise) that I would need to parse myself. I was, however, provided with a separate, external schema document for the objects actually returned - and I'm trying to somehow feed it to `wsimport` so it generates the classes for them as well.

I'm trying to accomplish that through JAX-WS / JAXB customization file like this:

```
<jaxws:bindings xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
                xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
                xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                wsdlLocation="wsdlLocation.wsdl">

    <jaxws:bindings node="wsdl:definitions">
        <jaxws:bindings node="wsdl:types" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb">
            <jaxws:bindings node="//s:schema[@targetNamespace='wsNamespace']">
                <jaxb:bindings node="//s:element[@name='Method_XMLResponse']//s:any">
                  ...
                </jaxb:bindings>
            </jaxws:bindings>
        </jaxws:bindings>
    </jaxws:bindings>
</jaxws:bindings>
```

Looks like `wsimport` picks the right location to customize (gave me numerous error meesages with properly designated line number in the WSDL), but I can't figure out how to fill the `<jaxb:bindings>` element to make `wsimport` generate classes from the external schema. Is it even possible? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Passing the external schema to wsimport with a `-b` option should be enough to have classes generated for it.  Do you have the option of passing the WSDL through an XSL transform before invoking wsimport, in order to replace the <xs:any> with the root element of the external schema?

Comment: Brilliant idea with applying an XSLT first, haven't thought of that, I'll sure give it a try!

Comment: Hi Tomasz, did you achieved the goal? I have the same issue. SharePoint WSDL in every response type has <any/> type and I want to expand this to complex structure (to omit parsing response). Unfortunately I'm not familiar with XSLT and Jaxb Bndings. Any tip will be great.

Comment: @MichałMech, as far as I remember, replacing the <any/> element in the WSDL worked for a simple test scenario (I replaced it manually instead of using XSLT), but at this point I guess it got too hacky for me and I ended up parsing the response in Java code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you are use mixed type with xs:any in your XSD. I think it usefull custimization for a mixed type following JAXB adjust:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxb:bindings
 xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" jaxb:version="2.0"
 xmlns:xjc= "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">

  <jaxb:globalBindings generateMixedExtensions="true"/>

</jaxb:bindings>
```

You can add external JAXB binding files to wsimport whith [-b parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html).

I think you can adjust xs:any with following ways:

**Skip shema:**

```
<xs:any processContents="skip" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" />
```

**Skip binding:**

```
@XmlAnyElement
  public List<Element> getAny();
```

**Strict schema:**

```
<xs:any maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" />
```

**Strict binding:**

```
@XmlAnyElement(lax=true)
  public List<Object> getAny();
```

and:

> with processContents=lax means any XML elements can be
>   placed here, but if their element names match those defined in the
>   schema, they have to be valid. XJC actually handles this exactly like
>   processContents='strict', since the strict binding allows unknown
>   elements anyway.

You can read more about [in this link.](https://jaxb.java.net/2.2.7/docs/ch03.html#compiling-xml-schema-mapping-of-xs-any)

May be help this answer to accomplish your JAX-WS / JAXB customization file.